# how to set ssh ControlMaster=no when using sftp or scp

Tags: ssh

I want to use SSH multiplexed connections and also forward my SSH agent.

When the SSH persistent socket is created by scp or sftp, the agent is not forwarded (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327100/295426). If I then use ssh over the same socket then the agent is not available.

If ssh creates the persistent socket then the agent IS available.

**Is there a way to have "ControlMaster no" for sftp/scp but auto for ssh?**

In my ~/.ssh/config I have

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master_%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 180
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue since 2016 with no official solution:
https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2621